# Diamond finding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have not been playing Minecraft very long, and I am having trouble find diamonds. I have looked at a few different articles saying that diamonds are most commonly found on level 8 and lower.

Are these articles true, or am I looking on the wrong level? I still have not found any diamonds. Is there a chance my world might have generated without any diamonds in it?

Comment: If you know how to mine you can find them pretty quick, i usually find my first diamond vein in less then an hour power playing from the start. Look into efficient mining techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Diamonds are rare.  VERY rare.  You can go for hours mining out in levels below 8 (preferable if you're a few levels above bedrock too) and not find a single block of diamond ore.

You're in the right area, you just need to expand your mining operation and be patient.  Do some branch mining.  Explore a deep cave.

Lava also tends to be at the same level as diamonds, which leads to the odd connection that diamonds can sometimes be found very close to lava, due to the wide area that lava can cover, so it might be worth (carefully) exploring around large lava pools too.  At the very least, you'll know you're at approximately the right depth level if you're finding lava pools occasionally.

Comment: You can find Diamonds at Y:16 or below.

Comment: I prefer to mine at Y:12 using the branch mining method. I seem to have far better luck at this level for finding diamonds, also, you should really mine every valuable resource you can find when branch mining as diamonds can often be just out of sight but next to other valuable resources. This includes coal, iron, lapis lazuli, redstone and gold. Mining straight tunnels, 2 high, 1 wide, and spaced with 3 unbroken blocks between each tunnel works very well for branch mining.

Comment: 13 can be a lucky number.I found diamonds at or near to.